# Use Javascript cookies inside Crosswalk (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, crosswalk

I'm using Crosswalk inside Android Studio to create a hybrid app that loads the html and js files locally and connects to a server via NodeJS.

For sessions I need to store cookies and for portability (I'll have to adapt the app for iOS) I'd like to store the sessions in JS cookies.

Can JS cookies be enabled inside Crosswalk?

PS: This is my base code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    libReader = new LibraryReader(this);
    //socket = new PrivateSocket(this);
    token = new LocalToken(this);

    XWalkView xWalkWebView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);


    XWalkPreferences.setValue("enable-javascript", true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);

    xWalkWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_Bind(this, xWalkWebView), "PHONE");


    xWalkWebView.clearCache(true);

    XWalkCookieManager mCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
    mCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    mCookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);


    xWalkWebView.load("file:///android_asset/cookie.html", null);
```

}